# view cannot access variable defined in controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I could not think how to write question for this problem.

So this is my problem.

I have two views

store-side-menu.blade.php

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

@foreach($store_categories as $cats)
    <a href="#">{{ $cats->category_of_store }}</a>
@endforeach
```

employ.blade.php

```
@section('side-menu-section')
  @include('fc.static.store-side-menu')
@endsection
```

In `employ.blade.php` is only includes the `store-side-menu.blade.php`. I have designed this structure due to need.

In controller I have

```
public function employment()
{
    $search = "";
    $store_categoies = Category::all();
    return view('fc.employ.employ', compact('search', 'store_categories'));
}
```

Now I have included `store_categories` in `compact` but `store-side-menu.blade.php` cannot access it. How do I achieve with its solution.

Comment: what error you are getting??

Comment: `Undefined variable: store_categories (View: C:\wamp64\www\FlashCart\resources\views\fc\static\store-side-menu.blade.php) `

Comment: Please add the error to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below and you should be good to go:

```
@section('side-menu-section')
  @include('fc.static.store-side-menu', ['store_categories' => $store_categories])
@endsection
```